# After installation of Snowsql I am getting Failed to initialize log. No logging is enabled: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\snowsql_rt.log'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

HI I have downloaded and installed SNowSQL onto my Windows Machine 64 bit machine

After entering command  snowsql -a zx12334 -u someone ; i am getting following error

Failed to initialize log. No logging is enabled: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\snowsql_rt.log'

Any idea what is reason.

In my config file I have enabled  log_file = ../snowsql_rt.log

Comment: *"In my config file I have enabled log_file = ../snowsql_rt.log"* - Why are you going up one directory?

Comment: @Tomalak that's default in the snowsql installation.

Comment: The entire way this thing installs on windows is weird. You run an msi installer which puts files in %USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\ , including the config file, and then when you run `snowsql` at the command line it does a secondary install to %PROGRAMFILES%\Snowflake SnowSQL\ , so when you run it, the executable from there it is not one directory below the config file anymore. Broken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Windows go to:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\
```

and update file **config** and replace this line:

```
log_file = ../snowsql_rt.log
```

with this line:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\log
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiu , i chnaged this to ~/.snowsql/snowsql_rt.log , the error disappeared

Comment: Yes, for linux, if you point your `log_file` entry to any location within your  `$HOME`: `~/`, the error will disappear. E.g. `log_file = ~/.snowsql_rt.log`

Answer (score 3):

The suggested answer for Windows did not work for me as (I think) it is missing `log_file =`. To fix my issue in Windows, I went to:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\config
```

And changed this:

```
log_file = ../snowsql_rt.log
```

to this:

```
log_file = %userprofile%\.snowsql\log
```

Answer (score 1):

To login SnowSQL client , open you windows command prompt
and run the following command:

```
snowsql -a your_acct_name.your_region -u your_username -o 
log_level=DEBUG
```

Also, if you are getting log error , then go to config file under snowsql application using

```
%USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\
```

and replace the log_file value with

```
%USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\log
```

Answer (score 0):

This post and the answer helped me solve this problem when launching snowsql from my home directory on Windows.

The error states that it cannot access it in the Users folder but snowsql tries to create the files in the parent directory from which it is launched.

For what it's worth, You can avoid the error on windows by launching snowsql from a different directory that is not restricted by Windows.

For example, I have a directory C:\WS\SnowSQL that I launched SnowSQL from this location and I did not get the error reported above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved with the next assignment to `log_file`, in order to save log file in the same location of config file :

```
log_file = ~/.snowsql/snowsql_rt.log
```